# What does Linux do with existing files in a mount point?

Tags: linux, mount

If I attempt to mount a folder that already has files in it, does linux give me an error message or go ahead and show both the mounted filesystem and the files that were already in the folder?

Comment: Could always try it out with some test files, no?

Comment: I would of if I could. It just worked out that I didn't have anything to test with. I tried unmounting and mounting the drive in question but the results were inconclusive because they both had the same files.

Comment: Is there a way to make the folder unwriteable so that files *can't* exist there?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It will just be mounted, and the files disappear, coming back when the folder is umounted.

Comment: What do you mean by disappear? They continue to exist on the server and are just not shown or are the deleted?

Comment: I'll go have a quick check, but I think they are deleted.

Comment: My bad, they go away while it's mounted, but come back when it's umounted.

Comment: +1 The files are simply invisible while the directory is mounted "over" them. They never really go away, the are just inaccessible...

Comment: It works like a stack, if you mount something else, it hides the previous content. When you unmount, the previous stuff becomes visible again.

Comment: Is this the same if I remount instead of explicitly mounting?

Comment: I'm confused by how someone who said "coming back when the folder is unmounted" was able to say 3 minutes later "I think they are deleted". Thankfully for everyone else, the former is the reality here.

Comment: Suppose we have an empty partition at `/dev/sda1` and a folder with existing files in `/mnt`. What happens to the partition when it is mounted over `/mnt`? In my test the files in `/mnt` get copied over to the partition (Debian bullseye).

Answer (score 122):

When you mount a filesystem on a directory `/mount-point`, you can no longer access files under `/mount-point` directly. They still exist, but `/mount-point` now refers to the root of the mounted filesystem, not to the directory that served as a mount point, so the contents of this directory cannot be accessed, at least in this way. For example:

```
# touch /mount-point/somefile
# ls /mount-point/somefile
/mount-point/somefile
# mount /dev/something /mount-point
# ls /mount-point/somefile
ls: cannot access /mount-point/somefile: No such file or directory
```

There are ways to get a merged view of the mounted filesystem and the data that was already present, but you need an extra layer called a [union filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount).

Under Linux, there is a way to see the hidden files. You can use `mount --bind` to get another view of the filesystem where the mount point is. For example

```
mount --bind / /other-root-view
```

You'll see all the files in the root filesystem under `/other-root-view`.

```
# cat /other-root-view/etc/hostname 
darkstar
```

In particular, `/mount-point` will now be accessible as `/other-root-view/mount-point`, and since `/other-root-view/mount-point` is not a mount point, you can see its contents there:

```
# ls /mount-point/somefile
ls: cannot access /mount-point/somefile: No such file or directory
# ls /other-root-view/mount-point/somefile
/other-root-view/mount-point/somefile
```

Comment: Gilles, this answer just saved my butt when I needed to get some asterisk recordings that got saved underneath an NSF mount point! I always thought --bind had the same perspective as the user.  Thank you!

Comment: What about directories? If I mounted at `/mount-point/1/` then mounted another filesystem on `/mount-point/`, can I still access `/mount-point/1/`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yes, indirectly by using a bind mount as described in my answer.

Comment: Giles, this is a brilliant technique and has helped me analyze what’s on my own system. It has also helped with another question, which is how to check usage of all of the root directories without traversing mount points. Solution: `mkdir /r; mount --bind / /r; du -sh /r/*`. Thanks

Comment: @Manngo for future reference, this is not necessary.  `du -x` (equivalent to `du --one-file-system`) would have done that without the need for `--bind` shenanigans.

Comment: @Darael `mount --bind` makes a difference: if a filesystem is mounted on a non-empty directory in `/`, then `du -x /` will not count what's in that directory, because it's hidden by the mounted filesystem. With `mount --bind` you can get an unobstructed view of a filesystem.

Comment: @Gilles That's a very good point, though in general for "how to check usage of all the root directories without traversing mount points" I'd imagine it's unlikely there's much if anything being shadowed by mounts.

Comment: What if the `/` filesystem is almost full, you mount some `/mount-point/` with many files that disappear, and you keep filling up the `/`. Will the disappeared files make space for the new files, and consequently become overwritten?

Comment: @DrBeco If my bookshelf is full, and I hang a drape on it, does it make room for more books? Of course not.

Comment: Your analogy makes sense. Thanks for having the time to reply.